# Heroku cannot find module when path uses "../"

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I deployed my Node project that uses `express/mongoose` to Heroku and looked at the logs it showed

```
Error: Cannot find module '../models/Posts'
```

Which is required in my index.js file as

```
const Posts = require('../models/Posts');
```

This path works for me when testing on a local server. I can temporarily fix this by moving the model to the same folder as `index.js` and changing the path to `const Posts = require('./models/Posts');`.

It looks like Heroku is having trouble interpreting the `../`’s in my path correctly. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: In general you should never program using relative paths (aka: `../` and `../../` and the like) and always use absolute paths to your assets and content. Unsure how you app is structured or looks like, but that is really the best solution for NodeJS and tons of frameworks and even non-framework based programming.

Comment: I tried changing the route to `"/app/models/Posts"` but I still get `Error: Cannot find module '/app/models/Posts'`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had a bunch of `console.log()`s in my routes(`index.js`). Removing them fixed the problem.

Comment: Well, this might be *a* thing that fixed this issue, but it honestly sounds a bit crazy that logging to console would cause issues like this. Most likely your `console.log()` broke or delayed something in the `index.js`.

Comment: It is strange considering my app is working on heroku now with a console.log() used in a catch to return an error.  Maybe there was a console.log() that was trying to log something undefined. None the less its strange that somehow that was preventing heroku from reading the module.